# Azure Static Web Apps login with popup

Tags: azure-static-web-app

This query is regarding authentication/login in single page applications using Azure Static Web Apps (SWA).

With MSAL.js we can login either with a popup (`loginPopup`) or redirect(`loginRedirect`) as in Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-spa-sign-in?tabs=javascript2#choosing-between-a-pop-up-or-redirect-experience). But when working with SWAs, currently [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/authentication-authorization?tabs=invitations) only shows login by navigating to `/.auth/login/{provider}`. Is it possible to do popup based login in Azure SWA?

<sub>The request is for a solution where login initiator script knows if login succeeded e.g. in MSAL.js `loginPopup().then()`. I like to avoid using solutions like `window.open` where the initiator is unaware of login status.</sub>

Comment: With MSAL.js we can authenticate either by login popup or login redirect. When it comes to pop up based login for Azure, Azure static web apps supports login through modal dialog. Angular popup modals can be used when you are coding in angular. Can you provide me the code snippet for better understanding?

Comment: No. I am not using Angular. It is plain Javascript. E.g. `<a href="/.auth/login/aad">Login</a>` The sample I am following is Microsoft Developer youtube video at https://youtu.be/TygnLOA68B0?t=220

Comment: @kiranpradeep Did you manage to resolve this issue?